# Error wrapping link_to, image_tag and div_tag to produce this code

Tags: html, css, ruby

I have a simple HTML code, that needs to be converted in Ruby.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="single-work">
        <a class="work-thumb mb-35 light-box" href="works/img-05.jpg">
            <%= image_tag 'works/img-05.jpg' %>
            <div class="work-hover"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="work-excerp">
            <a href="single-services.html"><h2>Plugin Development</h2></a>
            <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulpu tate velit esse molestie consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Ruby Code.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="single-work">
        ---> <%= link_to((image_tag'works/img-05.jpg'), image_path('works/img-05.jpg'), 'class' => 'work-thumb mb-35 light-box')  %>
        <div class="work-hover"></div>
        <div class="work-excerp">
            <a href="single-services.html"><h2>3D Design</h2></a>
            <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulpu tate velit esse molestie consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need this `<div class="work-hover"></div>` inside that tag ( Look for this --> arrow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do something like:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="single-work">
        <%= link_to( image_path('works/img-05.jpg'), class: 'work-thumb mb-35 light-box') do %>
          <%= image_tag 'works/ing-05.jpg' %>
          <div class="work-hover"></div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="work-excerp">
            <a href="single-services.html"><h2>3D Design</h2></a>
            <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulpu tate velit esse molestie consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'not working' is hardly a good description for an error. What is happening? It does not create the link wrapping the HTML?

Comment: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2).

Comment: it's saying the same thing. wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2) I tried almost everything past 2 hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115068/discussion-between-ed-de-almeida-and-manshu).